# adding element table created by json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am beginner in using JSON. I am trying to make a table that contain the element from json and it works.

Here is the code

```
<script>
var js = '{ "classification" : ['+
'{ "Img":"banana.jpg" , "Species":"Banana", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Yellow" },' +
'{ "Img":"apple.jpg" , "Species":"Apple", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Red" },' +
'{ "Img":"grape.jpg" , "Species":"Grape", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Purple" },' +
'{ "Img":"tomato.jpg" , "Species":"Tomato", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Red" },' +
'{ "Img":"carrot.jpg" , "Species":"Carrot", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Orange" },' +
'{ "Img":"spinach.jpg" , "Species":"Spinach", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Green" } ]}';

var parser = JSON.parse(js);

//var x = parser.classification[0].Class;
</script>
<script>
var cTable = document.createElement('table');
cTable.id = "json-test";
cTr = document.createElement('tr');
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
th1.innerHTML = 'Img';
var th2 = document.createElement('th');
th2.innerHTML = "Species";
var th3 = document.createElement('th');
th3.innerHTML = "Class";
var th4 = document.createElement('th');
th4.innerHTML = "Color";
cTr.appendChild(th1);
cTr.appendChild(th2);
cTr.appendChild(th3);
cTr.appendChild(th4);
cTable.appendChild(cTr);
for(i = 0; i<6;i++)
{
    var cRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML = '<img src='+parser.classification[i].Img+'></img>';
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.innerHTML = parser.classification[i].Species;
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td3.innerHTML = parser.classification[i].Class;
    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
    td4.innerHTML = parser.classification[i].Color;
    cRow.appendChild(td1);
    cRow.appendChild(td2);
    cRow.appendChild(td3);
    cRow.appendChild(td4);
    cTable.appendChild(cRow);
}
document.body.appendChild(cTable);
</script>
```

However, I want to make additional input box below that allow user to input new element when user submit the form button. Is it possible to insert the value of input box into JSON object as well as the table row?

```
<form>
    <input id="img" type="text"/>
    <input id="species" type="text" />
    <input id="class" type="text" />
    <input id="color" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: By "*into JSON object as well*" - by json object did you mean the  you want to update the json string in `js` variable or add it to the parsed object? i'm not sure why you'd want to do the first case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/n9fwyw20/1/

I've made a couple of modifications, but I think you will understand them. Also I've added a event handler function to prevent your form to be submitted, so you will have to think of another way to send the form data, as for example an ajax submit.

```
formOnSubmit = function() {

    //Add your ajax call here

    var jsonRow = { "Img": document.getElementById("img").value , "Species": document.getElementById("species").value, "Class": document.getElementById("class").value, "Color": document.getElementById("color").value }

    addRow(jsonRow);
    parser.classification.push(jsonRow);

    return false;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var js = '{ "classification" : [' +
    '{ "Img":"banana.jpg" , "Species":"Banana", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Yellow" },' +
    '{ "Img":"apple.jpg" , "Species":"Apple", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Red" },' +
    '{ "Img":"grape.jpg" , "Species":"Grape", "Class":"Fruit", "Color":"Purple" },' +
    '{ "Img":"tomato.jpg" , "Species":"Tomato", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Red" },' +
    '{ "Img":"carrot.jpg" , "Species":"Carrot", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Orange" },' +
    '{ "Img":"spinach.jpg" , "Species":"Spinach", "Class":"Vegetable", "Color":"Green" } ]}';

var parser = JSON.parse(js);
var data = parser.classification;

function createTable() {
    var cTable = document.createElement('table');
    cTable.id = "json-test";
    cTr = document.createElement('tr');
    var th1 = document.createElement('th');
    th1.innerHTML = 'Img';
    var th2 = document.createElement('th');
    th2.innerHTML = "Species";
    var th3 = document.createElement('th');
    th3.innerHTML = "Class";
    var th4 = document.createElement('th');
    th4.innerHTML = "Color";
    cTr.appendChild(th1);
    cTr.appendChild(th2);
    cTr.appendChild(th3);
    cTr.appendChild(th4);
    cTable.appendChild(cTr);
    document.body.appendChild(cTable);
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        addNewRow(parser.classification[i]);
    }
}

function addNewRow(data) {
    var cTable = document.getElementById('json-test');
    var cRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML = '<img src=' + data.Img + '></img>';
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.innerHTML = data.Species;
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td3.innerHTML = data.Class;
    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
    td4.innerHTML = data.Color;
    cRow.appendChild(td1);
    cRow.appendChild(td2);
    cRow.appendChild(td3);
    cRow.appendChild(td4);
    cTable.appendChild(cRow);
}
window.addEventListener("load", createTable);

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () {
    var img = this.img.value;
    var species = this.species.value;
    var clas = this.class.value;
    var color = this.color.value;
    var obj = {
        "Img": img,
            "Species": species,
            "Class": clas,
            "Color": color
    }
    parser.classification.push(obj);
    addNewRow(obj)
    js = JSON.stringify(parser);
    return false;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duwfnqmz/1/)